# How can a write to workflow history list programatically

Tags: 2013, workflow-history

Can anybody help me. I have SP 2013 WF and I'm trying to write data to history log list using code

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(url))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        WorkflowServicesManager workflowServiceManager = new WorkflowServicesManager(web);
        var workflowInstanceService = workflowServiceManager.GetWorkflowInstanceService();
        var workflowInstances = workflowInstanceService.EnumerateInstancesForListItem(_currentDogovor.ParentList.ID, _currentDogovor.ID);
        WorkflowInstance wf = workflowInstances[0];
        SPWorkflow.CreateHistoryEvent(web,wf.Id,0,web.CurrentUser,TimeSpan.Zero,"Information",string.Format("CreateWeb function called."),string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Execution of this code throw an exception

> "Value cannot be null."

Why `SPWorkflow.CreateHistoryEvent` is not working in SP WF 2013?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this...

```
SPWorkflow.CreateHistoryEvent(this.workflowProperties.Web, this.workflowProperties.WorkflowId, eventId, time, “Outcome text”, “Description text”, “Other Data text”);
```

https://anothersharepointblog.wordpress.com/tag/createhistoryevent/